# Different ways of show notifications from tray bar

Tags: delphi, notifications, delphi-2009, trayicon

What are the alternatives to balloon hints to show notifications from the tray bar?

What I want to achieve is something like Skype notifications, so I want to also have the feature of piling up notifications (in Skype we have John is online, Marc is online and Jim is online at the same time). How can I achieve this?

Moreover, something nicer looking than the balloon hint would be better.

Comment: Whatever solution you choose, please take this (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff808316.aspx) into account

Comment: +1, exactly, that's really annoying (I would say much more than the famous paperclip :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use  the `TJvDesktopAlert` component which is part of the [`JVCL`](https://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JEDI_Visual_Component_Library) library, you can find an example in this directory jvcl\examples\JvDesktopAlert\JvDesktopAlertDemo.dpr

[image]

[image]
<sub>(source: [agnisoft.com](http://www.agnisoft.com/deepak/blog/DesktopAlert.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Looks nice. TMS has one that looks like it. Just tossing that out in case anyone has TMS and has overlooked it.

Comment: Check how such components work with taskbar located not at the bottom. Eg. I have taskbars always on the top and can hardly imagine other position.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create your own form and popup it as the tray notification at corresponding position.

Comment: Ok, but there is no a way to say "tell windows this form is a notification"? Or I need to program the behaviour "from scratch

Comment: What you mean with that notification ? You simply show your form when some event happens to your application

Comment: Something happens, e.g. your application get some instant message. You will handle list of your own popup forms, there you will create the new one and place it above the last (if some already exists), so you will get the cascade popup forms. Each instance of that popup form can also have a timer which hide itself and tell to the list "hey one of our forms left us, we need to move down".

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom form and show it next to the system notification area. [LMD ElPack](http://www.lmdinnovative.com/products/lmdelpack/) includes TElTrayInfo component for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Growl: http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/

It is a good looking UI

Comment: As far as I see it is a stand alone application, I am asking for a Delphi programming techinque.

Comment: It is a standalone app but you communicate with it via a .NET or COM API, i.e. you can add good looking notifications to your Delphi app very easily and they "pile up" just as you describe.

Comment: Right. The idea is that you off-load the notification portion to a separate program. Several different programs can all off-load their notifications to Growl. The user gets uniform control and a uniform appearance of notifications. Growl seems more prevalent on Mac. See also, [Snarl](https://sites.google.com/site/snarlapp/home).

Comment: Ok, so when I would like to use your application I will have to install also another software ? In that case I would leave your program and look for something else, beacuse I hate this kind of distributions.

Comment: Growl should be optional (or more appropriately, there should be an automatic fallback onto growl when it's installed).

Comment: So when I don't install that Growl or something with the main application I will get none or standard baloon notification ? The only thing I appreciate on this solution is that uniform appearance for more applications.